# addEventListener fires only once

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

I'm trying to detect the orientation change for the responsive design. A specific function must be called when it occurs.

I try two different ways to do it :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', headerSlider , false);
```

Or

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {

        headerSlider();
});
```

Both work but only once. 
For exemple, if i'm in the portrait mode, i switch to landscape mode, the function is fired. But when i want to go back to the portrait mode again. The function is no longer called.

Please note i tried to use "orientationchange" instead of "resize" and the result is exactly the same

Thanks for your help

Comment: For me it is working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/2q6LuL3s/

Comment: hum... that's very strange

Comment: how did you use orientationchange()? As from the API documentation, $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
// do stuff here}); this should work on every orientation change, except if $.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled is set to false.